# vue axios delete request not working in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios

### Vue component

```
    methods: {
    removeCategory(index) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
            let id = this.categories[index].id;
            console.log("ID="+id);
            if (id > 0) {
                axios.delete('/api/categories/' + id);
            }
            this.categories.splice(index, 1);
        }
    },
```

### Routes Api

```
Route::delete('/categories/{category}', 'CategoryController@destroy');
```

### Controller

```
    public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    $this->authorize('delete', $category);
    $category->delete();
    return $category;
}
```

Put request is working fine for inserting and updating data, but DELETE request is not able to delete data from the database.
Thanks

Comment: When you say "DELETE request is not able to delete data from the database", what do you mean by that? Is there any errors? Please provide some additional info.

Comment: not it doesn't show any error, but data is not deleted from the database

Comment: Can you check your console or network tag in your browser? That might provide some error data.

Comment: Yes, I do but doesn't show any error, my POST request is working fine which is the same as that, maybe ELoquent Delete is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel check CSRF token.
You need to add X-CSRF-TOKEN in the request header

You can read this doc : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the answer yet, quick fix as:

Remove the model binding in your **Controller**.
Grab specific category with an id.
Authorize and delete it.

*(no need to modify the **Component** and the **Route**)*